# Фиксированное меню и IE9

Tags: css

Internet Explorer 9 абсолютно не хочет корректно работать с моим кодом, как оптимизировать решение?

**Internet Explorer 9:** [скриншот](http://ssmaker.ru/922c28f7.png)

**Google Chrome:** [скриншот](http://ssmaker.ru/9bf6c6ac.png)

---

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus facere, deserunt incidunt repellendus illo totam cum repellat ipsam nemo autem consectetur. Explicabo totam iste voluptate magnam vero, aspernatur aut, ad officiis accusantium, voluptatem deserunt, neque? Est, similique dolore corporis sunt non quisquam, recusandae voluptatibus eligendi, ab placeat nulla aspernatur natus beatae, facilis nesciunt vitae sed iste earum! Ea error obcaecati, earum voluptates dolorum explicabo quisquam unde laboriosam eius, quas enim vel, quam temporibus rerum, recusandae officiis vero molestiae nemo consequuntur nesciunt sed fugit accusamus? Culpa labore doloribus doloremque in, harum perspiciatis reiciendis. Culpa doloremque excepturi eaque voluptate, vero, accusantium dolor nobis debitis deserunt, reiciendis magnam veritatis iusto sapiente aperiam nisi adipisci, similique fugit autem. Suscipit similique animi possimus. Obcaecati explicabo cupiditate blanditiis amet molestiae necessitatibus magnam impedit voluptatem corporis ex error, fugiat facere, id vel, pariatur perspiciatis magni. Ipsa tenetur beatae facere, temporibus iure molestiae nostrum nemo repellat. Enim, vero hic velit, nihil nesciunt non modi quasi reprehenderit esse quos asperiores perspiciatis iusto corporis fugit ut similique. Officia necessitatibus quidem, aspernatur est aperiam. Veritatis recusandae mollitia sequi ut, quasi nisi repellat nulla! Voluptatibus, numquam dolore, assumenda, illum suscipit odit quod aliquid nobis eaque in quaerat deleniti qui iusto voluptates perspiciatis nostrum dignissimos optio est commodi culpa animi? Voluptatum, esse possimus fugiat magni. Laborum eius libero quos commodi excepturi reprehenderit deleniti labore autem magni eaque ipsam, non rerum unde ducimus sit modi quod est reiciendis dolores debitis. Deleniti facere debitis necessitatibus ipsam, suscipit repudiandae doloremque labore, illo tenetur. Harum hic, perspiciatis fugiat minus est voluptatem quae odio architecto explicabo recusandae eius, officia quidem consequuntur dicta quos aperiam molestiae a corporis quia. Iste, facere similique mollitia dolorum soluta. Inventore ad exercitationem asperiores expedita unde eum similique, odit quisquam repudiandae, facilis aliquam laboriosam quam sapiente molestiae soluta rem obcaecati magnam a. Dolor, voluptates laborum odit, maiores voluptas dolores excepturi corporis cum eos vel animi quasi alias! Laudantium ea, est explicabo non omnis consectetur accusamus officiis blanditiis autem voluptatibus animi eos, atque nulla quae vel ad iusto. Veritatis vitae voluptates, tempora autem doloremque porro sed repudiandae amet laudantium dolores corrupti, delectus eveniet et tenetur quo quos. Voluptates dignissimos expedita et enim consectetur ea distinctio nesciunt! Asperiores in ipsam voluptatibus optio quis vero maiores, neque officiis. Delectus aliquam nam, hic beatae enim minus non! Eveniet repellat, facere ex obcaecati iusto vitae aliquam soluta minus iure voluptates nobis quas, veritatis possimus ad quae. Quis veniam, doloribus blanditiis iste, at ipsa recusandae rem modi nostrum ex similique repellendus ullam deserunt error, maiores iure nulla odit! Adipisci enim obcaecati tempora eligendi ex libero provident, quaerat fugit voluptas minima recusandae dolorem, veniam dicta earum beatae voluptatum inventore quod similique eveniet sit quas, ad maiores architecto. Dicta deserunt provident, ratione quibusdam quisquam fugit qui officiis consectetur a. Harum quia reprehenderit iure aperiam magni eaque amet in modi saepe laborum repellat obcaecati excepturi officiis impedit voluptate soluta sed suscipit perferendis consequatur magnam nemo nobis, libero, eveniet. Corrupti sequi adipisci ipsa explicabo in, laudantium quaerat assumenda ab aut delectus possimus doloribus harum cum debitis nemo, ipsum blanditiis quidem! Provident soluta eius a perferendis nemo, rerum, necessitatibus debitis et expedita nisi iste consectetur tenetur laudantium omnis eligendi rem maiores quis, animi praesentium pariatur numquam saepe. Ratione odit maiores natus temporibus tempora, exercitationem deleniti sapiente similique animi facere libero vitae, fuga id qui amet reprehenderit dicta quidem. A maxime dolorem, possimus, perspiciatis debitis omnis expedita iste laboriosam, et ipsam asperiores obcaecati quae quasi non, odio voluptates eveniet repellat quis. Cupiditate aut distinctio magni fuga, rerum temporibus quisquam, ab eligendi adipisci! Vel odio iusto, omnis dolor illum ab, quibusdam rem quisquam saepe, dolores accusamus beatae, harum temporibus optio reiciendis architecto sapiente magni dignissimos quidem consequatur doloribus. Maxime rerum adipisci magni voluptate, mollitia tempora, temporibus fuga error exercitationem excepturi, odit unde numquam veritatis debitis! Facilis esse accusamus accusantium enim aspernatur earum, eius, libero ad id ut voluptatibus. Odio ipsa excepturi perferendis rerum veniam, quae, culpa illum? Quas voluptas consequuntur qui iusto repudiandae vitae laboriosam quam repellendus obcaecati deleniti quidem dicta dignissimos cupiditate, aliquid assumenda nesciunt ipsa ab perspiciatis quis error ex eveniet eligendi nam natus earum. Totam deserunt nam reiciendis nobis id, molestiae omnis magni, repellendus commodi rerum quidem veniam fuga, dicta officia, labore. Aspernatur nobis esse blanditiis repellat nisi eius reprehenderit, delectus voluptate autem temporibus impedit a, molestiae odio! Placeat laborum voluptatum consectetur reprehenderit commodi fugit porro ullam, id ad dolorum nihil ratione, repudiandae tempore, eveniet impedit! Reiciendis adipisci amet, praesentium fugiat, suscipit fugit voluptates dolores ab, dolore cumque at? Temporibus deserunt accusantium, repellendus quod quia, ratione delectus neque quae in voluptas voluptatibus culpa. Commodi quisquam ipsam asperiores praesentium accusamus veniam iusto id perferendis porro quasi, maiores assumenda nobis adipisci aliquam ea, qui sequi odio incidunt quam. Doloremque atque, magnam saepe odio distinctio ipsum tenetur dolorem totam beatae, excepturi nam eius dolore laboriosam commodi temporibus aliquid sit! Sequi placeat eveniet numquam inventore voluptates nam nisi accusantium necessitatibus soluta, in repudiandae eligendi, iusto illum voluptatem asperiores aliquid, laborum, molestias ratione quidem officiis quis cumque fuga sint. Iste voluptatum facere sed quidem et nostrum quam doloremque incidunt, ipsum, quisquam, ad voluptate asperiores reprehenderit iusto molestiae, enim soluta? Tenetur hic modi sint expedita veniam eligendi, cum fugiat in deserunt quidem, consequatur obcaecati tempora perferendis esse reiciendis numquam labore ipsa animi? Ducimus placeat, dolor assumenda. Accusamus dolores ipsum at hic! Neque ipsa fuga qui reiciendis cum est earum, quos, excepturi iste recusandae, dolorum incidunt porro. Praesentium hic nobis voluptatibus eius eaque obcaecati mollitia, voluptatum incidunt reiciendis suscipit reprehenderit necessitatibus qui cupiditate quia nisi, beatae dolores odio harum dolor. Repellat, voluptatibus, cum at consectetur dolores excepturi perferendis debitis eligendi non, obcaecati totam velit fugiat aliquid quisquam rem ducimus est delectus repellendus placeat ex aperiam sit vel! Unde sint ullam cupiditate, quis laborum fuga! Sed explicabo, quos temporibus tempora soluta quam tempore vel numquam mollitia fugit molestiae eaque accusantium dolores, iure omnis recusandae. Quod autem, exercitationem distinctio maiores eos! Eos sequi veniam, sunt cupiditate ad. Libero nobis recusandae, delectus amet saepe sit reiciendis provident perferendis aliquam tempore ad facilis ea voluptate.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
nav {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
.content {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Возможно ie9 не понимает теги html5,
добавьте shim and Respond.js.*

```css
header {
  display: block;
}

nav {
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    background: #000;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    color: #fff;
}
.content {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
      
      <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus facere, deserunt incidunt repellendus illo totam cum repellat ipsam nemo autem consectetur. Explicabo totam iste voluptate magnam vero, aspernatur aut, ad officiis accusantium, voluptatem deserunt, neque? Est, similique dolore corporis sunt non quisquam, recusandae voluptatibus eligendi, ab placeat nulla aspernatur natus beatae, facilis nesciunt vitae sed iste earum! Ea error obcaecati, earum voluptates dolorum explicabo quisquam unde laboriosam eius, quas enim vel, quam temporibus rerum, recusandae officiis vero molestiae nemo consequuntur nesciunt sed fugit accusamus? Culpa labore doloribus doloremque in, harum perspiciatis reiciendis. Culpa doloremque excepturi eaque voluptate, vero, accusantium dolor nobis debitis deserunt, reiciendis magnam veritatis iusto sapiente aperiam nisi adipisci, similique fugit autem. Suscipit similique animi possimus. Obcaecati explicabo cupiditate blanditiis amet molestiae necessitatibus magnam impedit voluptatem corporis ex error, fugiat facere, id vel, pariatur perspiciatis magni. Ipsa tenetur beatae facere, temporibus iure molestiae nostrum nemo repellat. Enim, vero hic velit, nihil nesciunt non modi quasi reprehenderit esse quos asperiores perspiciatis iusto corporis fugit ut similique. Officia necessitatibus quidem, aspernatur est aperiam. Veritatis recusandae mollitia sequi ut, quasi nisi repellat nulla! Voluptatibus, numquam dolore, assumenda, illum suscipit odit quod aliquid nobis eaque in quaerat deleniti qui iusto voluptates perspiciatis nostrum dignissimos optio est commodi culpa animi? Voluptatum, esse possimus fugiat magni. Laborum eius libero quos commodi excepturi reprehenderit deleniti labore autem magni eaque ipsam, non rerum unde ducimus sit modi quod est reiciendis dolores debitis. Deleniti facere debitis necessitatibus ipsam, suscipit repudiandae doloremque labore, illo tenetur. Harum hic, perspiciatis fugiat minus est voluptatem quae odio architecto explicabo recusandae eius, officia quidem consequuntur dicta quos aperiam molestiae a corporis quia. Iste, facere similique mollitia dolorum soluta. Inventore ad exercitationem asperiores expedita unde eum similique, odit quisquam repudiandae, facilis aliquam laboriosam quam sapiente molestiae soluta rem obcaecati magnam a. Dolor, voluptates laborum odit, maiores voluptas dolores excepturi corporis cum eos vel animi quasi alias! Laudantium ea, est explicabo non omnis consectetur accusamus officiis blanditiis autem voluptatibus animi eos, atque nulla quae vel ad iusto. Veritatis vitae voluptates, tempora autem doloremque porro sed repudiandae amet laudantium dolores corrupti, delectus eveniet et tenetur quo quos. Voluptates dignissimos expedita et enim consectetur ea distinctio nesciunt! Asperiores in ipsam voluptatibus optio quis vero maiores, neque officiis. Delectus aliquam nam, hic beatae enim minus non! Eveniet repellat, facere ex obcaecati iusto vitae aliquam soluta minus iure voluptates nobis quas, veritatis possimus ad quae. Quis veniam, doloribus blanditiis iste, at ipsa recusandae rem modi nostrum ex similique repellendus ullam deserunt error, maiores iure nulla odit! Adipisci enim obcaecati tempora eligendi ex libero provident, quaerat fugit voluptas minima recusandae dolorem, veniam dicta earum beatae voluptatum inventore quod similique eveniet sit quas, ad maiores architecto. Dicta deserunt provident, ratione quibusdam quisquam fugit qui officiis consectetur a. Harum quia reprehenderit iure aperiam magni eaque amet in modi saepe laborum repellat obcaecati excepturi officiis impedit voluptate soluta sed suscipit perferendis consequatur magnam nemo nobis, libero, eveniet. Corrupti sequi adipisci ipsa explicabo in, laudantium quaerat assumenda ab aut delectus possimus doloribus harum cum debitis nemo, ipsum blanditiis quidem! Provident soluta eius a perferendis nemo, rerum, necessitatibus debitis et expedita nisi iste consectetur tenetur laudantium omnis eligendi rem maiores quis, animi praesentium pariatur numquam saepe. Ratione odit maiores natus temporibus tempora, exercitationem deleniti sapiente similique animi facere libero vitae, fuga id qui amet reprehenderit dicta quidem. A maxime dolorem, possimus, perspiciatis debitis omnis expedita iste laboriosam, et ipsam asperiores obcaecati quae quasi non, odio voluptates eveniet repellat quis. Cupiditate aut distinctio magni fuga, rerum temporibus quisquam, ab eligendi adipisci! Vel odio iusto, omnis dolor illum ab, quibusdam rem quisquam saepe, dolores accusamus beatae, harum temporibus optio reiciendis architecto sapiente magni dignissimos quidem consequatur doloribus. Maxime rerum adipisci magni voluptate, mollitia tempora, temporibus fuga error exercitationem excepturi, odit unde numquam veritatis debitis! Facilis esse accusamus accusantium enim aspernatur earum, eius, libero ad id ut voluptatibus. Odio ipsa excepturi perferendis rerum veniam, quae, culpa illum? Quas voluptas consequuntur qui iusto repudiandae vitae laboriosam quam repellendus obcaecati deleniti quidem dicta dignissimos cupiditate, aliquid assumenda nesciunt ipsa ab perspiciatis quis error ex eveniet eligendi nam natus earum. Totam deserunt nam reiciendis nobis id, molestiae omnis magni, repellendus commodi rerum quidem veniam fuga, dicta officia, labore. Aspernatur nobis esse blanditiis repellat nisi eius reprehenderit, delectus voluptate autem temporibus impedit a, molestiae odio! Placeat laborum voluptatum consectetur reprehenderit commodi fugit porro ullam, id ad dolorum nihil ratione, repudiandae tempore, eveniet impedit! Reiciendis adipisci amet, praesentium fugiat, suscipit fugit voluptates dolores ab, dolore cumque at? Temporibus deserunt accusantium, repellendus quod quia, ratione delectus neque quae in voluptas voluptatibus culpa. Commodi quisquam ipsam asperiores praesentium accusamus veniam iusto id perferendis porro quasi, maiores assumenda nobis adipisci aliquam ea, qui sequi odio incidunt quam. Doloremque atque, magnam saepe odio distinctio ipsum tenetur dolorem totam beatae, excepturi nam eius dolore laboriosam commodi temporibus aliquid sit! Sequi placeat eveniet numquam inventore voluptates nam nisi accusantium necessitatibus soluta, in repudiandae eligendi, iusto illum voluptatem asperiores aliquid, laborum, molestias ratione quidem officiis quis cumque fuga sint. Iste voluptatum facere sed quidem et nostrum quam doloremque incidunt, ipsum, quisquam, ad voluptate asperiores reprehenderit iusto molestiae, enim soluta? Tenetur hic modi sint expedita veniam eligendi, cum fugiat in deserunt quidem, consequatur obcaecati tempora perferendis esse reiciendis numquam labore ipsa animi? Ducimus placeat, dolor assumenda. Accusamus dolores ipsum at hic! Neque ipsa fuga qui reiciendis cum est earum, quos, excepturi iste recusandae, dolorum incidunt porro. Praesentium hic nobis voluptatibus eius eaque obcaecati mollitia, voluptatum incidunt reiciendis suscipit reprehenderit necessitatibus qui cupiditate quia nisi, beatae dolores odio harum dolor. Repellat, voluptatibus, cum at consectetur dolores excepturi perferendis debitis eligendi non, obcaecati totam velit fugiat aliquid quisquam rem ducimus est delectus repellendus placeat ex aperiam sit vel! Unde sint ullam cupiditate, quis laborum fuga! Sed explicabo, quos temporibus tempora soluta quam tempore vel numquam mollitia fugit molestiae eaque accusantium dolores, iure omnis recusandae. Quod autem, exercitationem distinctio maiores eos! Eos sequi veniam, sunt cupiditate ad. Libero nobis recusandae, delectus amet saepe sit reiciendis provident perferendis aliquam tempore ad facilis ea voluptate.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что-то не помогло.

Comment: @РодионПоляков,жаль, что не помогло. Возможно еще из-за max-width проблему, но нужно смотреть.